# traversing Linked List python

Tags: python, linked-list

take a look at this sample code:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,breed,name):
        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name
    
    def bark(self):
        print("my name is {}".format(self.name))

class Cat:
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age = age
    
    def meow(self):
        print("my name is {}".format(self.name))

myDog = Dog("daschund","bingo")
myCat = Cat(78)
myCat.meow()
```

note: the class Cat does not inherit from the dog class. so when you try to run this code; it throws an attribute error since  'Cat' has no attribute called 'name'.

now take a look at this code for traversing a linked list

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,data=None,next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next 

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def print_linkedlist(self):
        if self.head == None:
            print("Linked list is empty!")
        else:
            n = self.head
            while n != None:
                print(n.data)
                n = n.next
```

just like the initial example; here LinkedList has no attribute called data or next; because it doesn't inherit from the Node class.  So how then does the print_linkedlist() method in the LinkedList class access the data and reference/pointer that the Node class contains?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: the method accesses methods `data` and `next` of the object stored in `self.head`, which should be of type Node.

`print_linkedlist()` is accessing `data` and `next` attributes that belong to the object that is returned when accessing LinkedList's `head` attribute. I assume that this `LinkedList` object will have a `Node` object set as its `head`. Each `Node` will point to the next `Node` and `LinkedList` objects are simply the way to keep reference of the first `Node` of each list.